# How to use NotebookDynamicExpression on a timed event

Tags: dynamic, button, user-interface, save, autosave

I have a few questions for how the feature [NotebookDynamicExpression](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookDynamicExpression.html) was used in [ResourceFunction[SetNotebookAutoSaveTime]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SetNotebookAutoSaveTime/). Below is the entire definition:

```
SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[] := 
  SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[EvaluationNotebook[]];
SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[nb_NotebookObject] := 
  SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[nb, 60];
SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[n_] /; NumberQ[n] || n === None := 
  SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[EvaluationNotebook[], n];
SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[n_Quantity] := 
  SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[EvaluationNotebook[], n];
SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[nb_, n_?NumberQ] := 
  SetOptions[nb, 
   NotebookDynamicExpression -> 
    If[n > 0, Dynamic[Refresh[NotebookSave[nb], UpdateInterval -> n]],
      Inherited]];
SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[nb_, None] := 
  SetOptions[nb, NotebookDynamicExpression -> Inherited];
SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[nb_, n_Quantity] := 
  With[{qm = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[n, "Seconds"]]}, 
   SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[nb, qm] /; NumberQ[qm]];
```

However I wish to only focus on these three lines:

```
SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[n_] /; NumberQ[n] || n === None := 
  SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[EvaluationNotebook[], n];
SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[nb_, n_?NumberQ] := 
  SetOptions[nb, 
   NotebookDynamicExpression -> 
    If[n > 0, Dynamic[Refresh[NotebookSave[nb], UpdateInterval -> n]],
      Inherited]];
SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[nb_, None] := 
  SetOptions[nb, NotebookDynamicExpression -> Inherited];
```

In the documentation the author writes, ***"Notebooks only auto-save if they have been saved once and have changed in memory."*** But I also notice that author uses `NotebookSave[nb]`. Does `NotebookSave[nb]` monitor if edits have been made? If not, where in the code does that take place? How might this action be started and stopped with a toggle button?

Comment: I think the documentation is incorrect on the "and have changed in memory" part, at least in MMA 12.3.1 on Win10-64. You can easily test that part by creating a new notebook, then setting the autosave to 10 seconds. First of all, it will prompt you to save immediately (which doesn't seem in accordance with the described behavior). Then, once you have saved it, you can monitor the modification time of that file and see it change every 10 seconds. I assume that the periodic saving of the file, even though no change was made in those 10s, is what causes the modification.

Comment: In fact, I also noticed that running `SetNotebookAutoSaveTime[None]` afterwards will NOT actually stop the periodic autosaving, which is a bit more worrisome.